# Prove that $m$ is regular.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For an interval $I=\{(x_1,x_2,…,x_p)|a_i≤x_i≤b_i  (i=1,2,…,p)\}$, we define a set function
$$m(I)=\prod_{i=1}^p(b_i-a_i)),$$
and 
$$m(I_1∪…∪I_n )=m(I_1 )+⋯+m(I_n)$$
whenever the intervals are pairwise disjoint. (Note: For p=1,2,3, then m is length, area, and volume respectively.)

Intervals are in the context of rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis ch 11

**Question**
Prove that $m$ is regular.

**My work**

Let $A$ be an interval.

Given $\epsilon >0$, choosing 
$$G=(a-\epsilon/2, b+\epsilon/2)=(a_1-\epsilon/2,b_1+\epsilon/2)\times (a_2-\epsilon/2,b_2+\epsilon/2)\times\ldots\times(a_p-\epsilon/2,b_p-\epsilon/2)$$ and $F=[a+\epsilon /2, b-\epsilon /2]$
Then,
$$m(G)=\prod_{i=1}^pb_i-a_i-\epsilon$$ 
and 
$$m(F)=\prod_{i=1}^pb_i-a_i+\epsilon$$

After that,Am I getting, $m(G)-\epsilon\leq m(A)\leq m(F)+\epsilon$

Clear this doubt..

Comment: What have you tried? You can take intervals really close to each other, by  a certain factor of $\epsilon$ and you're done since $p$ is finite.

Comment: What is your definition of "regular"?

Comment: refer rudin PMA page 312 for regular def.@EricWofsey

Comment: @ gloom  This is  sufficient because $m$ is defined on the class of subsets of $R^n$ each  element  of  which is  presented as a  union  of  finitely many  family  of  pairwise  disjoint intervals.